# needs some work doing/done

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, american-english, british-english

The following is an example sentence from the Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English:

> As you can see, the house needs some work **doing** on it.

[source](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/see)

It seems that many native speakers prefer "done" to "doing." Is this a case of AmE/BrE difference?

Comment: That sentence is extremely surprising to me, an American English speaker, because it sounds completely wrong.  I would be very curious to hear from British English speakers.

Comment: To me, a British English speaker, it sounds perfectly normal!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very odd to me. I would have said:

*The house needs some work **done** on it.*

However, after doing a bit of "research" I have come to the (sad) conclusion that it is a less common but acceptable alternative form.

**1.** [Dictionary of Contemporary English](https://Dictionary%20of%20contemporary%20English): (Not Longman!)

> If someone else is going to do something for you, you can say that **you need something done** or **need something doing**:
> *I need my car fixed urgently.*
> *You need your head examining!*

**2.** Google search results:

"needs some work done" 1 400 000
"needs some work doing" 478 000 (i.e. a quarter of the total of the two forms)

**3.** Google [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=needs+some+work+doing%2Cneeds+some+work+done&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cneeds%20some%20work%20doing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cneeds%20some%20work%20done%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

Comment: I was surprised too, but I found some examples in live usage, like [Fiesta xr2i - project ? needs some work doing](https://www.fiestaturbo.com/forums/fiesta-xr2i-project-needs-some-work-doing-vt170225/)  I would be careful about calling it "acceptable", though - it might be regional or dialectal, but clearly most speakers are not familiar with it.